# Kaa device connection baseurl

Tags: kaa

Should kaa baseurl connection be ssl enabled eg. https://myurl.it/, so all communication over ports 9888, 9889, 9997 and 9999 are ssl encrypted?

Or is this builtin in the aka stack - so communication can be over http?

Answer (score 0):

Kaa provides 2 default kinds of transport that cover data exchange needs of all the Kaa cluster services based on HTTP 1.1 and TCP. See [Default transports](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Transports#Transports-Defaulttransports) documentation page at outdated documentation.
For other cases use [this](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Welcome/.) Kaa documentation.